# how to log variables in the django source code

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out how the framework runs behind the scenes, and have been successful using pdb.set_trace(), and I've been able to log statements to the console, but when I try to import logging and log variables, like so, just as an example (deliberately selecting a string variable):

```
def as_ul(self):
    "Returns this form rendered as HTML <li>s -- excluding the <ul></ul>."
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return self._html_output(
        normal_row='<li%(html_class_attr)s>%(errors)s%(label)s %(field)s%(help_text)s</li>',
        error_row='<li>%s</li>',
        row_ender='</li>',
        help_text_html=' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
        logging.warning('%s',  row_ender)
        errors_on_separate_row=False)
```

I get an error(full traceback below)

At the top of the page I've included `from sys import logging`

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application, run
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import ISO_8859_1, UTF_8
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Users/user/Documents/repos/djangoFormDissection/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals  # NOQA
ImportError: cannot import name signals
```

Comment: what is `row_ender`?

Comment: valid question; fixed my example to show the function this is in.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is `logging` in the `self._html_output(` function call as an argument?

Comment: I looked at the docs about logging in python, and thought this was a correct context for it. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but when I log a statement in a function, it works; it only breaks when I log a variable.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `logging.warning('%s',  row_ender)` as an argument to `self._html_output(` function:

```
def as_ul(self):
    "Returns this form rendered as HTML <li>s -- excluding the <ul></ul>."
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    row_ender = '</li>'
    logging.warning('%s',  row_ender)

    return self._html_output(
        normal_row='<li%(html_class_attr)s>%(errors)s%(label)s %(field)s%(help_text)s</li>',
        error_row='<li>%s</li>',
        row_ender=row_ender, # use the variable here
        help_text_html=' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`logging` is not in the `sys` module, so you shouldn't import it from there. It's a standalone module in its own right. All you need is `import logging`.